# Access an entity property by id

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm creating a form with 2 entity lists.

One list contains an entity with Id and Name, let's call it **X**. My other list, let's call this list **Y**, contains a **UserId**, **X_Id** and **Score**.

Since the **Y** list doesn't contain all the corresponding I need the loop the **X** list in my twig template and only for the filled in **Y** entities I want to display the score, based on the **X_id**.

Now I want to check if there is a **X** entry for my **X_id**. I could of course loop my **Y** list on every **X** item, but isn't there a better way to do this?

I have the following code, obviously this isn't working:

```
 {% for x in xList %}
     <strong>{{ x.name }}</strong><br/>
     Score:<br/>
     <input type="text" name="value[{{ x.id }}]" value="{{ yList.get(x.id).score }}"/>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you use Symfony Form or you are building your form in a twig file?

Comment: I'm building the form my self.

Comment: You have to iterate over yList and check for the corresponding item!.
What is the type of yList?.
can you put your controller code?

Comment: If you're using [Doctrine ORM](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html), you can define a one-to-many relation between X and Y, and let Doctrine "do the dirty job".

Comment: Why you don't index your Y list by X.id? Then you will just need `{{ yList[x.id].score }}`

Comment: @YassineGuedidi is there a "official" way in symfony2 to create that index? We also use a custom framework at the office and I created an function for that, otherwise I keep using that function.

Comment: I don't think it's related to symfony at all. It just depends on how you build your list.